# Optimal control with final state inequality constraint

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, optimal-control

$$\begin{cases}\min\limits_{{\bf u}(t)}&\displaystyle\int_0^{t_f}ϕ(\mathbf{u}(t))\,{\rm d}t\\&\dot{\bf x}(t)=A{\bf x}(t)+B{\bf u}(t)\\&C{\bf x}(t_f)=α\\&g({\bf x}(t_f))\le β\\&{\bf x}(0)=0\end{cases}$$
I am dealing with an optimal control problem of the above form, where $A$, $B$ are matrices and $C$ is a vector of appropriate size. $\phi$ and $g$ are scalar functions of the control and state respectively.

I would like to use the Pontryagin’s minimum principle to solve this problem but I am not sure how to deal with the final state inequality constraint $g(\mathbf{x}(t_f)) \le \beta$. 
Can anyone help me out and give me some ideas about how to set up the principle?

Comment: This will not yield exactly the optimal solution, but you could replace the inequality $g(\mathbf{x}(t_f)) \le \beta$ by adding a barrier function to the terminal cost.

Comment: I tried to squeeze the formula so that it can shows completely on the bounty page but it has obviously failed :P

Comment: It is only one scalar inequality. You may solve the optimization without this constraint first and see what happens. If the inequality is not satisfied for the optimal solution (most likely) then the constraint is active, and you may do another attempt with the equality $g(x_f)=\beta$.